# Rye flour in starter

Tags: sourdough, rye

I have a recipe for sourdough starter, that says I should use rye flour. But which is that? I have grinded my own flour from whole rye berries. There is a lot of bigger parts from the outer layer of the grain in the starter. Will it work? Should I sift the flour before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should leave it as it is. The outer coating has a much higher concentration of natural yeasts which is what you want. You'll have a better chance of getting a successful starter if you use all of the ground berry.